# How to install and activate PDO for PHP 7?

Tags: php, pdo, installation, ubuntu-14.04, php-7

The [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) says:

> PDO and the [PDO_SQLITE](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0.

Now I've installed PHP 7.0.3 (`apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl`) on Ubuntu 14.04 and checked, whether PDO is installed -- on the CLI:

```
$ php -m | grep "pdo"
(empty output)
```

and in the browser:

[image]

There is no `pdo.ini` file and also nothing like `pdo.so`.

So, I would say, PDO is not installed.

**How to get PDO for PHP 7 working (on Ubuntu 14.04)?**

---

**EDIT**

I didn't want to install `php7.0-mysql`, since I thought, it would install the deprecated MySQL module. But it's not "just" depricated anymore -- it has been removed in the version 7.0, see [docu](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php):

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0.

So `apt-get install php7.0-mysql` actually installs the modules PDO_MYSQL and MySQLi.

Nevertheless I wonder, why the module PDO and is not displayed in the modules list. And where is its `pdo.ini` and its `pdo.so` file? And it's also strange, why the SQLite module is not installed, althpugh it actually should be, see [docu](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlite.php): "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0.".

Comment: Have you had a look at `apt-cache search pdo`?

Comment: `apt-get install php7-mysql`

Comment: @fusion3k `E: Unable to locate package pdo-mysql`

Comment: @automatix there was a typo in my original comment (corrected 1 min ago). BTW search before, the exact command can be `apt-get install php7.0-mysql` or similar. Follow deceze suggestion and then run appropriate `install` command

Comment: @deceze Yes. But didn't found anything proper. What exaclty do you mean?

Comment: @automatix try to search for mysql instead of pdo. Is your apt pkg list updated?

Comment: In short: you need to install the right package. `apt-cache search ..` and `apt-cache show ..` are your friends here to figure out what that may be. Asking on SO to have it pointed out to you is of course an alternative...

Comment: According to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04): `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Comment: @fusion3k Thank you very much -- this solved the problem. See the question update.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard PHP 7 is released and is not a RC anymore. So it's a bit another context. Would you please remove the "duplicate" flag from the question. Thanks.

Comment: Since the duplicate contains the same answer @automatix I don't see that the duplicate should be removed. Do you think having your question marked as a duplicate is a bad thing?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Usually it's actually not a good thing and every SO member should try to avoid this. Bt the reason, why I would to remove "duplicate" is, as described about -- that it (IMO) another question because of another context. Anyway, I can also understand your point. It's a gray area.